# How to inverse the structure of eager loaded data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm loading a product eagerly with its relationship data in Laravel.

```
$product = Product::with('attributeValues.attribute')->find($id)->get();
```

Currently I get the response structure as follows.

```
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Shirt A",
    "attribute_values": [
        {
            "attribute_value_id": 1,
            "attribute_value": "small",
            "attribute": {
                "attribute_id": 1,
                "attribute": "size"
            }
        },
        {
            "attribute_value_id": 1,
            "attribute_value": "medium",
            "attribute": {
                "attribute_id": 1,
                "attribute": "size"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The structure I expected to get is as follows.

```
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Shirt A",
    "attribute": [
        {
            "attribute_id": 1,
            "attribute": "size",
            "attribute_values": [
                {
                    "attribute_value_id": 1,
                    "attribute_value": "small"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_value_id": 1,
                    "attribute_value": "medium"
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The current relationships of the models are as follows

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function attributeValues(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeValue::class, 'product_attributes');
    }
}

class AttributeValue extends Model {
    public function attribute(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
    }
}

class Attribute extends Model { }
```

Currently I'm succeeded getting this structure correctly by using product and getting it attributes separately using raw queries. I'm trying to achieve a Eloquent way of doing this task.

The tables I have are as follows

**products**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

**product_attributes**

```
+----+------------+--------------------+
| id | product_id | attribute_value_id |
+----+------------+--------------------+
```

**attribute_values**

```
+----+--------------+-------+
| id | attribute_id | value |
+----+--------------+-------+
```

**attributes**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | attribute |
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have products and attributes table and product_atributes as intermediate table between products and attributes
and it has attribute_value field as pivot.

Then in you Product model you should have a many to many relationship with Attribute model with pivot.

```
// Product
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes')
        ->withPivot('attribute_value');
}
```

This way you can get product's attributes along with their pivot values.

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->load('attributes'); // same as with() in query builder
```

When you want the pivot values you can access it via `->pivot->value`

```
foreach($product->attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->pivot->attribute_value;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have updated the question with the tables as well.
I tried your solution. But id didn't work. Gives me this error.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_attributes.attribute_id'

Comment: @Camille I have seen your table structure. your implementation is correct with many to many relationship. I don't think you can change to your expected structure.